# ERROR: Repository not found message given when following the instructions for Jekyll-Bootstrap

Tags: git, github, twitter-bootstrap, rubygems, jekyll

Github pages not working for me when using Jekyll-Bootstrap.

I followed the instructions here:

```
http://jekyllbootstrap.com/
```

The instructions say:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/plusjade/jekyll-bootstrap.git USERNAME.github.com
$ cd USERNAME.github.com
$ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:USERNAME/USERNAME.github.com.git
$ git push origin master
```

I used the personalized install code (means my github name rather than "USERNAME")

I get this error when I try to do the last "$ git push origin master"

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

How do I get this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have created a git repository on GitHub named `USERNAME.github.com`. Are you new to GitHub? Just make sure you log in and then go to your dashboard which is on http://github.com
Somewhere on that page you'll see a button "New repository". Use that to create a repo named `USERNAME.github.com` . Once that's done, run the Jekyll Bootstrap commands again and it should work.

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I've been using Github for about a year. Not an expert but I can definitely get around my repos. Your setup instructions are very easy. Practically impossible to mess up for someone who has used git and github before. But still, I did everything numerous times with slight variations to no success. To get your repo up on my page I created my own repo, DLed yours separately and then just copied and pasted into my local folder before "add ." and commit/pushing back to github. Github says it may take 10 minutes for a repo to be ready (I waiting as long as 30 minutes).

Comment: After I create the repo on github I am at the Global setup:/Next steps: page. What do I do next? Do I go to your step "2 - Install Jekyll-Bootstrap" or is there something I have left to do after immediately creating myusername.github.com? I believe I'm neglecting some steps but am not sure what they are.

Comment: @NewB do you have google chat or skype etc. Somewhere we can chat? I'll walk you through trying to set this up. I agree it should be pretty straight forward if you know git and GitHub. plusjade@gmail.com and/or plusjade on skype.

Comment: USERNAME.github.com is case sensitive. Thanks!

Comment: For me, I solve it by adding ssh keys. you may refer to https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. I noticed that the instruction give commands that include `USERNAME.github.com` while my actual Jekyll-Bootstrap blog is located at `USERNAME.github.io`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when the user had no permissions over the organization. Check its status if you have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I face this issue and pull my hair out and figure out the solution. It occurs since your git remote repo still points to `github.io`. Instead use `github.com`

```
 git remote rm origin
 git remote add origin git@github.com:myorganization/myrepo.github.com.git
```

Then run setup

```
 rake setup_github_pages
```

It prompts for repo url, enter your url which has `.com` extension `git@github.com:myorganization/myrepo.github.com.git`

Answer (score -1):

I ran into same problem. I have created username.github.io repository when I cloned the jekyll repo as per the steps:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/plusjade/jekyll-bootstrap.git USERNAME.github.io
$ cd USERNAME.github.io
$ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:USERNAME/USERNAME.github.io.git
$ git push origin master
```

I also used CNAME file to redirect to my custom domain. It works fine for sometime pushes successfully and can commit. But after sometime it gives the same error.

> > Permission denied (publickey).
> >     fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
> >
> > Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> >     and the repository exists.

At this time _site folder is created on your root at username.github.io 
I couldn't know the solution yet but deleting the remote repo and pushing into empty repo again.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this an Answer or do you have a [new Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)?