# Linking computer and pushing to github for the first time

Tags: git, ssh, github

I am trying to connect to github for the first time.

I followed these instructions (as well as Rails 3.0): http://help.github.com/create-a-repo/

But I am getting these errors:

```
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:rubikcubes/ticketee.git
$ git push origin master -u
The authenticity of host 'github.com (207.97.227.239)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is ##:##:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? y
Please type 'yes' or 'no': yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,207.97.---.---' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Identity added: /Users/name/.ssh/id_rsa (/Users/name/.ssh/id_rsa)
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:rubikcubes/ticketee.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:rubikcubes/ticketee.git (push)
```

I set up the SSH, but maybe I did it wrong?

Comment: You did step 1, "Create a new repo"?

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen https://github.com/rubikcubes lists `ticketee` as a repo created five hours ago.

Comment: Note that HTTPS protocol is recommended over ssh

Comment: possible duplicate of [ERROR: Repository not found message given when following the instructions for Jekyll-Bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133578/error-repository-not-found-message-given-when-following-the-instructions-for-je)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you spelled your username and repo correct (case sensitive)

May be related:
[ERROR: Repository not found message given when following the instructions for Jekyll-Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133578/error-repository-not-found-message-given-when-following-the-instructions-for-je)

Comment: That was it! I didn't use capitalization when I needed to. I ended up deleting it and starting over.